# 2 forms on one page, unicode as value for switch/break function

Tags: php

Sorry for the title that makes no sense.

I have a page with 2 forms on it, for them I have a switch/break for the submit depending on which submit is clicked.

```
 switch($_POST['submit']) {
    case 'register':
 break;
    case 'login':
 break;
    }
```

And then the HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"></input>
```

Originally I had the values in unicode like `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="&#xf105">;`

But it didn't work in the switch function. Basically how do I get it to work using the unicode, as I would like to use an icon font instead of just text.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catch it with the any field name or submit name change

```
<form >.........
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"></input>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="login"></input>
</form>
```

php file

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// you condtion 
}
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
// you condtion 
}
```

Comment: Yay, replaced the switches with the if statements instead, like you showed. Thank you!

Comment: switch is faster then IF but less then 5 conditions , it is  preferable to use IF condition